# Why is p tag pushing down parent div?

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I have two divs taking up half of the screen each. When I add a p tag inside the second div, it pulls it down. Why is this happening? I creating an html email so I have to use only inline styling and can't reference outside stylesheets with grid systems.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jzcxhp2L/1/

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 49%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 49%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For email html you're probably better off using tables rather than divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p>` is a block element and you're nesting it inside an inline element. That's not supposed to happen and is causing the layout issue. Block elements will create a new line.

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it
>   can).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

This layout might work better for you. https://jsfiddle.net/jzcxhp2L/7/

```
<div style="display: flex; height: 300px; width: 95vw; margin:0 auto;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px; flex:1;">
    <p>asdlfadsf</p>
    <p>asdlfadsf</p>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px; flex:1;">
    <p>asdlfadsf</p>
    <p>asdlfadsf</p>
    <p>asdlfadsf</p>
    <p>asdlfadsf</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `float:left;` to them and add the `margin` value you desire .

```
    <div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; float: left; margin: 5px; width: 49%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;float: left;margin: 5px; width: 49%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "Why is this happening?"

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to your styles. Also, if you are assigning some border, its better to use `box-sizing:border-box;` This will not let the border affect the element width.

Hope this helps

Comment: "Why is this happening?"

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` has his own margin

try to put the margin-top and/or bottom to 0px

```
p {
    margin-top: 0px ;
    margin-bottom: 0px ; 
}
```

or try to give your `<p>` tag  a class with display = inline

```
.class-inline {
    display: inline ; 
}
```

or use inline style:

```
<p style="display: inline">
```